# How to set Class value to spring bean property?

Tags: java, spring, class, javabeans

Hey, what is the best way to set a bean's property with Class value ? Regarding XML configuration. For a bean like this :

```
public class FilterJsonView extends MappingJacksonJsonView {

    private Set<String> filteredAttributes;
    private Class clazz;

    public Set<String> getFilteredAttributes() {
        return filteredAttributes;
    }

    public void setFilteredAttributes(Set<String> filteredAttributes) {
        this.filteredAttributes = filteredAttributes;
    }

    public Class getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just inject the class name, and Spring will convert it to a `Class` object for you, e.g.

```xml
<bean class="com.x.y.FilterJsonView">
   <property name="clazz" value="com.x.y.SomeClass"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Which answer should I accept ? The earlier or the more accurate :) ?

Comment: I'd say whichever one seems most correct to you, and for what you are doing. Overall, the goal is to help the community by finding the "best" answers.

Answer (score 9):

Just supply the class name. Say you want `clazz` to be `String.class`:

```xml
<bean id="beanId" class="FilterJsonView">
    <property name="clazz" value="java.lang.String"/>
</bean>
```

Spring has a [`PropertyEditorSupport`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html) implementation called [`ClassEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/ClassEditor.html) that handles the conversions.