# Spring Beans Mule - Property of type interface/class

Tags: java, spring, ejb, javabeans, mule

I am trying to specify a bean that has an interface `IServiceHandler`. I want to allow the property to be set to anything that implements the `IServiceHandler` interface. For example `GenericServiceHandler`.

Here's the bean code I have in my Mule flow:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="Fake_Proxy" class="xxx.FakeWebServiceProxy" scope="prototype">
        <spring:property name="serviceHandler" value="xxx.GenericServiceHandler">
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

`FakeWebSericeProxy` has a property called `serviceHandler` which is of type `IServiceHandler`.

The issue is that I keep getting the following message when I try running the Mule application:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ca.mpac.esb.component.webservice.IServiceHandler] for property 'serviceHandler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834311/how-to-set-class-value-to-spring-bean-property) that Spring will automatically deal with a situation like this, but it doesn't seem to work for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field in `FakeWebServiceProxy` seems to be of type `IServiceHandler` not of type `Class`, if you just want to accept the class, change the type of the property to `Class`. Spring should then convert the String value to the appropriate `Class` instance and inject it.

But if you want to inject an object instance of type `IServiceHandler` instead, you must first create a bean and then inject it into the `Fake_Proxy` bean:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="serviceHandlerBean" class="xxx.GenericServiceHandler" scope="prototype"/>
    <spring:bean id="Fake_Proxy" class="xxx.FakeWebServiceProxy" scope="prototype">
        <spring:property name="serviceHandler" ref="serviceHandlerBean"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured you could create the serviceHandler as a bean then inject it as a reference, but is this something that most people using Spring would accept?

Comment: @TheAJ: Why not? You could even inline the `serviceHandlerBean` definition in the assignment, like `<property name="serviceHandler"><bean class="xxx.GenericServiceHandler"/></property>` instead of the define and reference pattern.