# How to inject Class<T> as bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have the following class `UserAuthorityRepository` as repository:

```
@Repository
public class UserAuthorityRepository extends BaseRepository<UserAuthority, Long> implements IUserAuthorityRepository {

public UserAuthorityRepository(Class<UserAuthority> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
  super(domainClass, em);
}

}
```

And in `UserAuthorityService` I have:

```
@Service
public class UserAuthorityService extends BaseService<UserAuthority, Long> implements IUserAuthorityService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAuthorityService.class);

@Autowired
private IUserAuthorityRepository userAuthorityRepo;

public UserAuthorityService() {
  super();
  LOGGER.info("UserAuthorityService Has Been Created");
}

@Bean
@Override
public Class<UserAuthority> getDomain() {
  return UserAuthority.class;
}

@Override
public IBaseRepository<UserAuthority, Long> getRepository() {
  return userAuthorityRepo;
}

}
```

But my application gets exception at startup as follow:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bia2hd.dao.impl.UserAuthorityRepository required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Class value to spring bean property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834311/how-to-set-class-value-to-spring-bean-property)

Comment: @JoeC Thanks, But I have no xml configuration, it's all annotations.

Comment: So potentially silly question here... but why do you need to inject a `Class` in this context?  The only legal value for your constructor argument is `UserAuthority.class`, so why not set that explicitly in your superconstructor call instead of depending on it getting injected (and then only the `EntityManager` needs to be injected)?

Comment: Despite of what you think about whole silly question here, the problem is more complicated. there is dozen of repositories whit such situation.

Comment: Please see my other post

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it(not very pleasing, but working).

```
@Configuration
public class Beans {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @PostConstruct
   public void createClassBeans() throws ClassNotFoundException {

      ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

      scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));

      ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext)
            .getBeanFactory();

      for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("my.package")) {
         Class<?> bean = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
         beanFactory.registerSingleton(bean.getName(), bean);
      }

   }

}
```

And

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Long> implements IUserRepository {

   UserRepository(@Qualifier("my.package.User") Class<User> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
      super(domainClass, em);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@Configuration`?

```
@Configuration
public class InjectConfiguration {

    @Bean("providerEmployeeContext")
    @RequestScope
    public IEmployeeContext<Employee> providerEmployeeConfiguration() {

        return new EmployeeContext<>(sessionFactory(), Employee.class);
    }

}
```